# Accessible Tooltip Component /// Focus Order

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui, styled-components

I'm building an accessible tooltip component in React that is based off of Google's Material UI.

Our tooltips default to `open`, but a question comes up about focus order on the page.

Since tooltips are absolutely positioned, they won't follow logical focus order, nor can we set a `tabindex` value for every focusable element on the page.

From a React perspective, `<Tooltip> <button>Add Items</button> </Tooltip>`.

In the DOM, the tooltips are appended to `document.body` and have no relationship with the child component in React (e.g., `button`)

If a tooltip is shown, we'd ideally want to announce it instead of the `aria-label` of the child component (e.g., `button`).

Our tooltips' text is focusable, they also have a "close" (`X`) button, so each tooltip has two focusable items.

What can we do? Many thanks in advance for the help :)