# Altering the focus order of the page when a tooltip is shown

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, accessibility

I'm currently developing a custom Tooltip/Popover component. The way it works is basically a customized React-Popper wrapping a Trigger element. When the user focuses on the Trigger, the tooltip opens. When they blur, it closes.

The problem is, **the tooltip is generated at a top-level in the DOM structure**. It is not attached to the Trigger element but instead is created as a div at the root level. This obviously messes up the focus sequence as it puts the tooltip content at the end of the focus queue.

I can control the tooltip content, as I know it will always have the same structure (some action buttons and a Close button). **I've managed to force `.focus()` on the first button whenever the tooltip is visible**. This, however, does not solve my problem, because ***it is in fact skipping over all the other focusable elements on the page*** (which I have no control over).

What I need is **a way to alter the focus order to make the tooltip content be at the same "level" as the Trigger component** so they will be focused next to each other, and then resume the sequence with the next elements displayed on the page.

The only thing I've found is [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76344606/accessible-tooltip-component-focus-order) with absolutely zero answers.

Answer (score 1):

I've created a minimal demo:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-ibqwmn?file=src%2FApp.js

where you can check out my approach to your problem.

Solution explained:

1. Once the tooltip is `blurred` you find the next focusable element (not the greatest performance in the case of big documents). I'm sure you can play around and optimize it further.
2. You force-focus it and hide the tooltip. **Note** on this point: Since I had trouble forcing react to focus the element I used the accepted answer from here [How to focus on dynamically added Input field in react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72739930/how-to-focus-on-dynamically-added-input-field-in-react)

```
const handleTooltipBlur = () => {
    if (triggerRef && triggerRef.current) {
      const nextFocusableElement = findNextFocusableElement(triggerRef.current); // Implementation can be seen in the stackblitz link
      if (nextFocusableElement) {
        console.log('Next focusable element:', nextFocusableElement);
        setTimeout(() => {
          nextFocusableElement.focus();
        }, 200);
        setTooltipVisible(false);
      }
    }
  };
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. You've inspired me to try some new things. However this is far from ideal because the component will likely be used in pages with lots of content which is out of my control. I'm also not a big fan of using `setTimeout` as I find it to be clunky sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

I missed the simplest solution. The Popper library includes the `usePortal` prop. Setting it to `false` keeps the DOM structure unaltered, thus fixing my focus navigation problem.